# Could not resolve dependencies for project com.semantico.counter:persistence:jar:1.1.1

Tags: java, spring, jersey, maven-2, restful-architecture

When i run install Maven, it throws error like.

```
[INFO] java-COUNTER ...................................... SUCCESS [  1.093 s]
[INFO] java-COUNTER Utils ................................ SUCCESS [  1.312 s]
[INFO] java-COUNTER domain model ......................... SUCCESS [  1.593 s]
[INFO] java-COUNTER persistence layer .................... FAILURE [  2.843 s]
[INFO] java-COUNTER core functionality ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] java-COUNTER inbound message processor ............ SKIPPED
[INFO] java-COUNTER web commons .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] java-COUNTER message receiver ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] java-COUNTER client API definition ................ SKIPPED] java-COUNTER API implementation ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] STAR benchmarks ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] java-COUNTER admin UI ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] java-COUNTER reporting UI ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.029 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-08-06T17:01:33+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 26M/222M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project persistence: Could not resolve     dependencies for project com.semantico.counter:persistence:jar:1.1.1: Could not find artifact com.semantico.counter:utils:jar:tests:1.1.1 in project_lib (file:///F:\ConnectBooks\star_15Jul15\star_15Jul15\persistence/mvnLib) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please     read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1]     http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the     command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :persistence
```

My pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.semantico.counter</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.semantico.counter</groupId>
<artifactId>receiver</artifactId>

<name>java-COUNTER message receiver</name>

<packaging>war</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.semantico.counter</groupId>
        <artifactId>web-commons</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.codahale.metrics</groupId>
        <artifactId>metrics-servlet</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <!-- CD-1158 For double-click. NB: 2.1.0 is a bit old -->
        <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
        <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test scope -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-grizzly2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.riffpie.common.testing</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-test-support</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-apache-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.grizzly</groupId>
        <artifactId>grizzly-webserver</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.semantico.counter</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence</artifactId>
        <type>test-jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.semantico.counter</groupId>
        <artifactId>utils</artifactId>
        <type>test-jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-dep</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Container provided -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Your persistence.jar project has a dependency on your utils.jar project but your parent cannot resolve utils.jar. Do you have the com.semantico.counter:utils.jar installed in your local .m2 cache or your corporate repo? If com.semantico.counter:utils.jar is not in your local maven repo then you need to install it using mvn:install. Or you could install it in your corporate repo if you are using one. By default, mvn will check your local .m2, and then Maven central, but as your utils.jar is not in Maven central it needs to exist somewhere you parent build can resolve it from.

Answer (score 0):

Are you configuring a multi-module project? If so, have a [look](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html) at some examples of how to configure them. If this is the approach you are taking then the parent pom should declare your persistence and utils projects as modules:-

```
<modules>
        <module>persistence</module>
        <module>utils</module> 
</modules>
```

This way your parent should be able to access the jars resulting from building of the two modules - rather than having them as completely separate projects.